# Convert PDF to PNG inside browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf.js

I'm using Vue.js and trying to convert PDF to PNG (or another image format) inside browser.
Right now I'm able to read PDF from URL with `PDF.js` and Vue.js component [pdfvuer](https://github.com/arkokoley/pdfvuer) like this:

```
var self = this;
self.pdfdata = pdfvuer.createLoadingTask(
  "https://any-pdf-link"
);
self.pdfdata.then(pdf => {
  console.log(pdf.numPages)
})
```

What should I do next to convert it to image?

Comment: do you have an updates for that function? because I cant find a package for that function.

Answer (score 4):

Pdfvuer author here.

Pdfvuer/PDF.js renders PDFs as canvas elements. You can use the following code to generate a thumbnail from the first page.

```
let s = document.querySelectorAll('canvas')[0]
let imageDataUrl = s.toDataURL('img/png')
```

This will give you a base64 representation of the page.

Comment: Hi, this is an intriguing solution, however, please tell me what the 'canvas' inside the querySelector refers to.